# SSIS task for variables from another table

Tags: variables, ssis, lookup-tables

I'm very new to SSIS. Prior to this I have been writing ETL procedures manually, hence my lack of confidence or familiarity in this Environment. I know the basics like execute SQL and Import using a static query.

However, I'm looking for the best way to do the following:

I have a lookup table with a list of records containing to fields and a flag.

For each record where the flag says 0, i want to import records using a query to dump data to one common table using the two fields in the where clause of the query that comes from the above mentioned lookup table.

Could someone please help this noob.

thanks in advance. will be much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Conditional split". It allows splitting row to many streams by a condition. In your case it would be "[Flag] == 0"